# Spring Data JPA unable to find object with id

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm using JPA + Hibernate + Spring Data JPA on my project for working with database (MySQL).
Recently I've got an error which says:

```
org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException: Unable to find com.kanda.mindwire.domain.results.CognitiveResult with id 1700; nested exception is javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find com.kanda.mindwire.domain.results.CognitiveResult with id 1700

at org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils.convertJpaAccessExceptionIfPossible(EntityManagerFactoryUtils.java:379) ~[spring-orm-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:257) ~[spring-orm-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:528) ~[spring-orm-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-tx-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242) ~[spring-tx-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153) ~[spring-tx-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:149) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.2.3.RELEASE.jar:2.2.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:93) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.2.RELEASE.jar:5.2.2.RELEASE]
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy157.findByCompany(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
at com.kanda.mindwire.service.employee.EmployeeService.findWithFilter(EmployeeService.java:210) ~[classes/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
```

The code is trying to fetch the list of **Employee** entity which is having a **OneToOne** relation with **CognitiveResult**. I was thinking that it might be that there are **Employee** row with *cognitive_id=1700* but when I query my db I see that there are no such row.

The question is from where hibernate takes this **id** and how to fix it?

Here is my code:
**Employee.java**

```
@Table(uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {Employee_.EMAIL}))
@Entity
@Data
public class Employee extends BaseEmployee {

@Column
private String email;
....
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "company_id")
private Company company;

@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "cognitive_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
private CognitiveResult cognitiveResult;
...
}
```

**CognitiveResult.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "cognitive_results")
@Data
public class CognitiveResult extends BaseAssesment {
...

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "cognitiveResult")
private Employee employee;

@PreRemove
public void removeCognitiveForEmployee() {
    if (employee != null) {
        employee.setCognitiveResult(null);
    }
}
...
}
```

**EmployeeRepository.java**

```
public interface EmployeeRepository extends BaseRepository<Employee> {
...
    List<Employee> findByCompany(Company company);
...
}
```

**Company.java**

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Company extends BaseSettingsEntity {
...
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "company", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
private Set<Employee> employees = new HashSet<>();
/**
 * Logic for syncing employees
 * @param employee
 */
 public void removeEmployee(Employee employee) {
    if (!employees.contains(employee)) {
        return;
    }

    employees.remove(employee);
    employee.setCompany(null);
 }

 public void addEmployee(Employee employee) {
    if (employees.contains(employee)) {
         return;
    }

    employees.add(employee);
    employee.setCompany(this);
 }
...
}
```

All of my domain models inherit from **BaseEntity.java**

```
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS)
@Entity
@Data
public abstract class BaseEntity {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
@Column(updatable = false, nullable = false)
protected Long id;
...
}
```

And the exception occurs while calling findByCompany:

```
@Slf4j
public class EmployeeService extends BaseEntityService<Employee> {

private final EmployeeRepository repo;

public Map<String, Map<EmployeeJob, List<Employee>>> findWithFilter(EmployeeFilterWrapper filter, String username) {
    List<Employee> employeeList;
    User user = userService.findByUsername(username);
    Company company = user.getCompany();
    if (company == null)
        throw new InvalidCompanyException("Company not assigned for a user!");

    if (filter != null && filter.getDivisionsFilter() != null && CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(filter.getDivisionsFilter().getDivisions())) {
        employeeList = repo.findEmployeeByDivisionNamesAndCompany(filter.getDivisionsFilter().getDivisions(), company.getName());
    } else {
        employeeList = repo.findByCompany(company);
    }
...
}
```

Comment: `I was thinking that it might be that there are Employee row with cognitive_id=1700 but when I query my db I see that there are no such row.` Why did you think this? It's fine for these IDs to match anyway, since they're in different tables. The error says there is no `CognitiveResult` with id `1700`: "Unable to find com.kanda.mindwire.domain.results.CognitiveResult with id 1700"

Comment: @ChristopherSchneider I thought it because I'm fetcing list of `Employee` type and somehow get an error "Not found CognitiveResult with id 1700". So my guess that  there should be "not cleaned reference" to this `cognitive_id` in `Employee` table (and yes, I see that there are no such row in `CognitiveResult` table). 
As there are neither reference to it, nor `CognitiveResult` with such id, I don't understand where this 1700 came from...

Answer (score 0):

Found an issue. There where a link to missing `cognitive_id` in another table and it is missing because I was clearing those entites directly in db recently, but forgot that they reference other table.
It was a `Supervisors` table which is inherited from `Employee`

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "supervisors")
@Data
public class Supervisor extends Employee {
...
}
```